# No value repetition in same column

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have table called Dates. It contains foreign key to another table and a date (  2 columns in total). It can contain same foreign values but one foreign value cannot contain same dates (only different dates). For example.

```
FKey    |   Date
_____________________
1       | 13-01-2013
1       | 14-01-2013
2       | 14-01-2013
1       | 14-01-2013 <- this is wrong since it already contains this value above 
                        with same foreign key ( it should not be inserted)
```

I think i should do it by creating assertion to table using (CHECK clause) but i don't know how. Any ideas ?

Thank you

Comment: Plain old unique key constraint.

Comment: yeah but then then it wont allow same values for the different foreign keys. or  am i wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE Dates ADD CONSTRAINT u_Dates UNIQUE (FKey, Date);
```